# Can water of maddening be used as a thrown weapon to its full effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

It is not clear to me whether water of maddening can be used as a thrown weapon to its full effect, or only to the effect of unholy water.

The point of contention at my table was this sentence:

> In addition, any creature that is anointed with or drinks this fluid
>   must attempt a Fortitude save (drinking the water of maddening is
>   particularly effective—a creature that drinks the liquid takes a –4
>   penalty on its save to resist its effects). Success causes the
>   creature to become violently ill, vomit up the fluid, and become
>   sickened for 1d4 rounds.

Point being that to be hit by the water might not be the same as to be anointed and that the reference in spell description to its thrown weapon dosage might only be to the unholy water use of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using the spell [*water of maddening*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/water-of-maddening/)

The spell [*water of maddening*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/water-of-maddening/) (or, as originally presented at least three times—most recently in [*Book of the Damned*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601259700) (2017)—, *water of [Lamashtu](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lamashtu)*) allows the caster to take a standard action wiggling fingers, chanting nonsense, and disposing of 250 gp of powdered amber to create at up to close range a number of flasks of this "foul secretion" equal to the caster's caster level halved. (This is as per the spell's *Effect* entry.) Each flask the spell creates then exists forevermore nonmagically (as the spell's a conjuration [(creation)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration-Creation) spell with a [duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) of instantaneous), and each flask also functions as a [flask](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment-/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles/#TOC-Holy-Water) of [unholy water](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/curse-water), this latter detail making each flask a [splash weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon).

(I restate this all because a reader who reads only the spell's description might confuse the *water of maddening* spell with the [*create water*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-water/) spell (the effect of which, for example, can be dumped right onto some on-fire fool), but the *water of maddening* spell isn't really comparable to that: it creates *both* that foul secretion *and* the flask it's in!)

### Using a flask of [*water of maddening*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/water-of-maddening/)

The spell's description says that "[a]ny creature that is anointed with or drinks this fluid" may be affected by it. The word [*anointed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=anointed%20definition&rlz=1C1AOHY_enUS709US709&oq=anointed%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3113j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has no mechanical *Pathfinder*-specific definition, but, in real life—where a reader must go when the game is of no help—, is *really* precise, and its common usage *doesn't* usually mean *hucking a substance that's still in a flask at a dude*. (Such a definition, though, would make even more awesome [Psalm 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_23).) Nonetheless, this is [Lamashtu](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lamashtu) we're talking about, and that god might think it's *hilarious* to "anoint" someone in such a fashion.

Thus this reader can imagine a GM ruling whatever way he wants. That is, one GM may see the flasks as hideously unbalanced splash weapons and have the flasks work largely like flasks of unholy water, ruling that anointing someone means *taking a minute or so to smear ceremonially the contents on a helpless or willing creature's body* or something.  Another GM may see no problems with the flasks and rule that anointing foes by throwing flasks of *water of maddening* at them is totally legit.

(Paizo threads from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n8nw?Waters-of-Lamashtu) and [2013](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2peml?Waters-of-Lamashtu#1) sort of take it for granted that a flask of *water of maddening*'s full efficacy is realized when a flask is used as a splash weapon, but another thread from [2014](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r8q9?Waters-of-Lamashtu-touch-attack#1) disagrees. There's no official ruling on this aspect of the spell that I could find— creative director James Jacobs, for example, discusses the spell (and, by extension, the implications of other deity-specific spells) in a thread from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2myza?Can-Waters-of-Lamashtu-be-cast-by-nonworshippers), but he doesn't address the *anoint* issue.)

Honestly, from a worldbuilding perspective, this GM finds it slightly overpowered if a flask of *water of maddening* can be used for its full effect as a splash weapon. While the spell has a 250 gp material component, its casting time of 1 standard action means during a lull in an adventure a caster could create many, many flasks for free *via* the spell [*blood money*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-money/). This makes flasks of *water of maddening* essentially free for NPCs therefore making such flasks the go-to weapon for, for example, town guards who will find their jobs much easier if they can loose *en masse* ranged touch attacks that *either* [sicken](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Sickened) a lawbreaker on a successful save *or* deal 1d6 points of Strength and Dexterity damage to a lawbreaker on a failed save!

(For comparison, 1d6 Str and Dex ability damage is superior to most [poisons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison). And, although the *water of maddening* can't reduce a creature's Str or Dex below 1, because the save DC against the *water* is contingent on the spell's caster, the *water*'s save DC will likely be higher than the DCs of most poisons.)

That said, this GM would split the difference. A creature that has in hand a [flask of holy water](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment-/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles/#TOC-Holy-Water) can take a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity to splash the contents of that flask on an adjacent foe (usually one that's incorporeal because holy water flasks don't break against incorporeal creatures). With such rules in mind, this GM finds *that* process sufficiently close to "combat anointing." His house rule would be something like *An attacker wielding a flask of* water of maddening *can take a standard action to make a melee touch attack to anoint a creature. Success means that the creature suffers the full effect of the* water of maddening. (This way the town guards must at least get close to the lawbreakers!)